# Removing navigationbar from carouselPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm using navigation in Xamarin.forms to navigate between pages. but when using carouselPage to display multi pages i don't know how to hide/remove navigation bar on newly created carouselPage.

```
CarouselPage carouselPage = new CarouselPage();    
foreach (int index in myInts)
{
    string title = value[index].Round_title;
    string con = value[index].Content;
    string img = value[index].IMG;

    carouselPage.Children.Add(new BlankView(title, con, img));
}

await Navigation.PushAsync(carouselPage);
```

On all other pages i'm using this code to hide navigation bar. but since i don't have xaml for carouselPage,i can't use it.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

my question is how to remove navigation bar or how to create simple custom carouselPage.xaml that use pages.

Comment: Even you don't have xaml you still can remove navigation bar if carousel page is pushed to navigation page. What is the problem?

Comment: yes, i'm stupid didn't see NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(carouselPage, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip my mind that i could just change first argument and set is as new page.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(carouselPage, false);
```